# Showing a degree 6 polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_5$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Consider the polynomial $g(x) = x^6 + 2x^5 + 4x^4 + 3x^3 + x^2 + 2x + 3$. I am trying to show that this polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$. So far I have shown that $g$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ and hence has no linear factors over $\mathbb{Z}_5$. My next step is to show that $g$ has no irreducible factors in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ of degree $2$ or $3$. Is there a more efficient way of proving this, besides enumerating all of the irreducible polynomials of degree 2 or 3 in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ and then checking that none of them divides $g$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$?

Comment: Depending on what kind of computations you favor, you could alternatively compute $\mathrm{gcd}(g(X), X^{5^{2}}-X)$ and $\mathrm{gcd}(g(X), X^{5^{3}}-X)$, since $X^{5^{2}}-X$ is the product of all irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ of degree dividing $2$, and likewise $X^{5^{3}}-X$ is the product of all irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ of degree dividing $3$. It's unclear to me whether this really saves you any work, however...

Comment: Building on @AlexWertheim 's comment, since you've already established no linear factors, $g$ is either a product of three quadratics or two cubics, and looking at $(g,g')$ will show "easily" that there are no repeated factors. So the question is whether $g$ divides $X^{5^k}-X$ for $k=2,3$. But it does depend which sum you want to do.

Comment: I don't know whether this is of any use: $g(x)=3+\sum\limits_{k=0}^5 2^kx^{6-k}$.